# JSON data and deserialize

Tags: json

What is meant by deserializing json data.? What is the need to do it? I have been told to do this in my project when given a json object like this:

```
  ###format of a json record in a json file with .json extension
 ####
 '''{
 "firstname":"stack",

 "lastname":"overflow",
 "age":xx,
 "height":x.y,
 "phonenumbers":[
 {
 "type":"home","number":"xx-xx.xxx.x.x.x"
 },
 {
 "type":"fax","number":"x.x.x.x.x,x,x.x.x.x"
 }
 ]

 }
 '''
```

## defining a class object

Answer (score 1):

It means converting a JSON string into an object in your programming language, such as a Java POJO, a Ruby hash, a JavaScript object, etc.

The purpose is to allow your programming language to read and manipulate the data contained therein.